# How to get JavaScript AD to open its link in new window?

Tags: window

I got some code from a vendor that allows my organization to be awarded points when buyers purchase anything on the vendor's site when coming from my site. problem is, the window opens up WITHIN the ad, and not in a new window.

below  is the code...what do I need to add? or change? to allow it to open in a new window?

`<script type="text/javascript"> function vcp_gobad175(){ window.location='https://www.virtualcapoeira.com/store.htm?affcode=1039380713'; } </script> <div align="center"> <table border="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" id="capafftable1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> <tr> <td align="center" height="3"> <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="175" height="150" id="ba175x150_02" align="middle"> <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /> <param name="movie" value="https://www.virtualcapoeira.com/graphics/ba175x150_02.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" /><embed sRc="https://www.virtualcapoeira.com/graphics/ba175x150_02.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" width="175" height="150" name="ba175x150_02" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="https://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" /> </object> </td> </tr> <tr> <td align="center" height="3"></td> </tr> <tr> <td align="center"> <a target="_blank" title="Capoeira" style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: 700; color: #0066CC;" href="https://www.virtualcapoeira.com/store.htm?affcode=1039380713">VirtualCapoeira.com</a></td> </tr> <tr> <td style="font-size: 9px; color: #0066CC;" align="center"> <a target="_blank" title="Capoeira Music, Audio, MP3s, Downloads" style="font-size: 9px; text-decoration: none; color: #0066CC;" href="https://www.virtualcapoeira.com/music-store.htm?affcode=1039380713">Music</a>,  <a target="_blank" title="Capoeira Videos, DVDs, Downloads" style="font-size: 9px; text-decoration: none; color: #0066CC;" href="https://www.virtualcapoeira.com/video-store.htm?affcode=1039380713">Videos</a>,  <a target="_blank" title="Capoeira Instruments, Berimbaus, Atabaques, Pandeiros, Agogos, RecoRecos" style="font-size: 9px; text-decoration: none; color: #0066CC;" href="https://www.virtualcapoeira.com/berimbaus.htm?affcode=1039380713">Instruments</a> &  <a target="_blank" title="Capoeira Pants, Tops, Havaianas, Downloads" style="font-size: 9px; text-decoration: none; color: #0066CC;" href="https://www.virtualcapoeira.com/store.htm?affcode=1039380713">Gear</a> </td> </tr> <tr> <td style="font-size: 9px; font-weight: 700; color: #000000;" align="center"> <a target="_blank" title="Capoeira" style="font-size: 9px; text-decoration: none; color: #000000;" href="https://www.virtualcapoeira.com/index.htm?affcode=1039380713">Capoeira</a> - Are you Game?</td> </tr> </table> </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open)

```
function vcp_gobad175(){ 
    window.open('https://www.virtualcapoeira.com/store.htm?affcode=1039380713', '_blank');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)"   
onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','name',
'width=600,height=400')">Link</a>
```

This will open the url in a new window. Tested Working